# New to android, My simple name-getter app is crashing

Tags: java, android

hey guys I'm just writing a name getter app as I'm learning android and I am forced to close the app when it loads in the emulator. I'm quite new so It's probably something simple.

**namegetter.java**

```
package edu.calpoly.android.lab1;
// tools
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.LabeledIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NameGetter extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    // variables
    private android.widget.EditText textEdit_Name;
    private android.widget.Button button_Submit;
    private String string_Name;
    private android.content.Intent intent_GetText;
    private android.os.Bundle bundle;
    private android.widget.TextView textView_Top;
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.name_getter);

        // assign local variables
        textEdit_Name = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
        button_Submit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_Submit);
        textView_Top = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.LABEL1);
        button_Submit.setOnClickListener(this);

       bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

       bundle.getString(string_Name);
       textView_Top.setText(string_Name);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        string_Name = textEdit_Name.getText().toString();
        // create intent to pass
        intent_GetText= new Intent(this, HelloWorld.class);
        // pass to hello world activity
        intent_GetText.putExtra(string_Name, textEdit_Name.getText().toString());
        // initiate 
        this.startActivity(intent_GetText);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.calpoly.android.lab1"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="NameGetter"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="HelloWorld" ></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat? "adb logcat > file_to_write.to"

Comment: Also, your name_getter.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `getExtras()` is returning null.

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
bundle.getString(string_Name);
```

For more help, I suggest collecting the logcat (`adb logcat`) and posting the actual exception.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle.getString(string_Name);` probably throws a NullPointer since on first start, there will be no bundle added to the intent.

Comment: set initial value to "Nothing", still stops

Comment: You cannot set an inital value of a bundle as far as I am aware.

Comment: Any reason why you are using intents? They are not needed in this small example you showed.

Answer (score 1):

Out of a hunch I'd say you need to remove these two lines (null pointer exception):

```
 bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 bundle.getString(string_Name);
```

But it's hard to tell without the log file. Why? You won't have extras when tapping on your app from the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
bundle.getString(string_Name);
```

What are you trying to do there?

At the point of that second line, string_Name is null.

Comment: I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs/lab-1) I'm at 5.2. I set the initial value of the name variable to "nothing" and it still stops

Comment: You misread:


"Now that we've got the name retrieval activity completed, *let's update the **HelloWorld greeting Activity** to print out the name the user entered*. In the OnCreate method of HelloWorld.java:
Make a call to   this.getIntent().getExtras()   .... "

Those lines do not go in  `NameGetter`.

Answer (score 0):

Things I see to help make life better:

You don't have to use fully qualified `android.widget.EditText myEditText`.  Just `EditText myEditText` is fine.  Thats what your import statements handle  ;)

You have a minSdkVersion="12" in your manifest.  This may present issues, as that correlates to your app will only run on a device with android 3.1.  Try using minsdk=7 (Android 2.1 and above, much more prolific)

Likely a lot more wrong in manifest but I have only a few mins to look  :)